# work certificate - german company

Tags: germany, hiring

One german company I applied for asked me an interesting question:

To give my certificates (I presume my work certificates)

Issue is I do not have any work certificates as it is uncommon in Belgium and some of the companies I worked forn are now defunct...

Do you think if I'm saying I can give references, it will be enough?

Thanks

Comment: While I think it may be worthwhile to create a generic "What is an Arbeitszeugnis?" question, the top answer on [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60730/how-to-formulate-an-usa-style-recommendation-letter-to-be-used-optimally-as-a-ge?rq=1) basically answers your particular problem.

Comment: You could also offer to provide copies of your work contracts. That would at least document your work experience.

Comment: Is it possible that they meant school and university certificates? Those are usually requested in Germany.

Comment: Thanks for your replys, All. This is a first time for me that's why I'm asking. @JoeStrazzere, you are right. I need to ask, that simple, I'm making mountains here. Thanks Everyone for being here, I appreciate.

Comment: Everyone, I asked and it is Diplomas certificates. @StevenPessall, you were correct :)